# Proxy to forward Linux sytem calls using variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, system-calls, template-argument-deduction

I have a class that does some capability handling before calling a certain system call. This is done with a variadic template function:

```
class PrivilegesLinux
{
private:
    //! Prevent type deduction on template parameter.
    template<typename T> struct NoDeduce { typedef T type; };

public:

template<typename... PAR>
static int syscallProxy(cap_value_t capability,
    int(*syscall)(PAR...), typename NoDeduce<PAR>::type... params)
    {
        int rc = 0;
        // ... acquire capabilities

        // Forward to system call
        rc = (*syscall)(params...);

        // ... drop capabilities

        return rc;
    }
//...
};
```

This works nice on "normal" system calls. The system call's signature is deduced from the template arguments. The `typename NoDeduce<PAR>::type... params` forces a non-deduced context for the actual parameters. This might be replaced by [std::type_identity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) once I have a compiler supporting C++20. Here is an example that uses this function to acquire the privileges for a `kill` system call:

```
PrivilegesLinux::syscallProxy(CAP_KILL, kill, 1, SIGTERM);
```

However, as soon as I try to use a system call that has an `...` in its signature (e.g. `ioctl`), I get a compiler error (here I try to change the MTU size):

```
PrivilegesLinux::syscallProxy(CAP_NET_ADMIN, ioctl, nSocketID, SIOCSIFMTU, (char *)&ifr);
/*
error: no matching function for call to 'PrivilegesLinux::syscallProxy(int, int (&)(int, long unsigned int, ...) noexcept, const INT32&, int, char*)'
note: candidate: 'static int PrivilegesLinux::syscallProxy(cap_value_t, int (*)(PAR ...), typename PrivilegesLinux::NoDeduce<PAR>::type ...) [with PAR = {int, long unsigned int}; cap_value_t = int]'
note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 5 provided
*/
```

Obviously, the ellipsis as part of the parameter pack is causing this problem here. I thought I could solve this by using `std::forward`:

```
template<typename... PAR>
static int syscallProxy(cap_value_t capability,
    int(*syscall)(PAR...), typename NoDeduce<PAR>::type&&... params)
{
    //...
    rc = (*syscall)(std::forward<PAR>(params)...);
    //...
}
```

However, this fails with:

`error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'PrivilegesLinux::NoDeduce<long unsigned int>::type&&' {aka 'long unsigned int&&'} to lvalue of type 'pthread_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'}`

Does anyone have a suggestion to make this work with a single template function?
My current workaround is to define another template:

```
template<typename... SYSCALL_PAR, typename... PAR>
static int syscallProxy(cap_value_t capability,
    int(*syscall)(SYSCALL_PAR..., ...), PAR... params)
{
    // copy of the code above
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about reversing the deduction: a generic type for the function (avoiding deducing the types of the arguments) and deducing the arguments (maybe adding forwarding)?

I mean... something as

```
template <typename Func, typename... PARS>
static int syscallProxy (cap_value_t capability,
                         Func syscall, PARS && ... params)
 {
   int rc = 0;
   // ... acquire capabilities

   // Forward to system call
   rc = syscall(std::forward<PARS>(params)...);

   // ... drop capabilities

   return rc;
 }
```

Comment: There's a very minor difference; in this case you may have multiple instantiations of `SysCallProxy` which differ only trivially in `PARS`. Say `int` vs. `short`. In the original code, `PARS` would be uniquely determined by `syscall`. Probably not an issue in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might handle C-ellipsis explicitly, by adding an extra overload:

```
template<typename... PAR, typename ... Ts>
static int syscallProxy(cap_value_t capability,
                        int(*syscall)(PAR..., ...),
                        typename NoDeduce<PAR>::type... params,
                        Ts... args) // ellipsis arguments
{
    // Possibly check Ts... are "valid" type for ellipsis
    int rc = 0;
    // ... acquire capabilities

    // Forward to system call
    rc = (*syscall)(params..., args...);

    // ... drop capabilities

    return rc;
}
```

Note:

- `int(*syscall)(PAR..., ...)` might also be written `int(*syscall)(PAR......)`
- `Ts` are passed by value, as [ellipsis arguments types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions) are limited anyway.